# Store data with api-platform

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to store some a object, I pass my params but setter didn't work

My entity look like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Groups({"Project"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
     * @Groups({"Project"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Project", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Groups({"Project"})
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Status")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"Project"})
     */
    private $status;
```

And my service.yml :

```
resource.project.search_filter:
    parent:    "api.doctrine.orm.search_filter"
    arguments: [ { id: "exact", name: "partial", parent: ~ } ]
resource.project.order_filter:
    parent:    "api.doctrine.orm.order_filter"
    arguments: [ { "id": ~, "name": ~ } ]

resource.project:
    parent:    "api.resource"
    arguments: [ "AppBundle\\Entity\\Project" ]
    calls:
        -      method:    initNormalizationContext
               arguments: [ { groups: [ Project ] } ]
        -      method:    "initFilters"
               arguments: [ [ "@resource.project.search_filter", "@resource.project.order_filter"] ]
    tags:      [ { name: "api.resource" } ]
```

I don't understand how POST request work, because none of my entity properties are define.

It works with demo entities but not with mine, did i miss some annotation ? or my config is not complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass your entity as following :

with one slash

```
arguments: [ "AppBundle\Entity\Project" ]
```

Or if you pass your entity to a repository pass as following.

arguments: [ "AppBundle:Project" ]

and put following annotation into your repository

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProjectRepository")
```